# How to Rotate Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, rotation, genymotion

ive installed genymotion V2.5 emulator  on Windows 8  (on Eclipse luna 4.4.0)
and when im runnig an app with two screen rotation
,i wanna rotate Emulator Screen but rotation button on the emulator doesnt work at all

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I think some more elaboration on the question is needed to get an answer. Perhaps include some screenshots. Fx. elaborate on what "doesn't work at all" means (Please edit the question and not answer in comments).

Answer (score 3):

Two ways :

Button in the sidebar
CTRL + F11
Edit : And if it does not work, it's surely because the application in foreground is orientation locked.

Comment: how can i unlock the orientation ? my genymotion is for personal usage only not purchased